# Unable to receive/post data from mysql database server

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, server

i am send data using unitywebrequest but db/server is getting empty json string.

```
public class Credentials : Singleton<Credentials>
{
 
    public string email;
    public string password;
 
    public string ConvertToJason()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }
 
}
```

```
public class LogIn : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public InputField emailAddress;
    public InputField passwordField;
    public GameObject loadingCanvas;
    public GameObject loginButton;
    public GameObject loadingImg;
    string Url = "linkName";
 
    public void LoginButton()
    {
        loginButton.SetActive(false);
        loadingImg.SetActive(true);
       
        if (emailAddress.text == "" || passwordField.text == "")
        {
            Debug.Log("Empty");
            loginButton.SetActive(true);
            loadingImg.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
 
            Credentials.Instance.email = emailAddress.text.ToString();
            Credentials.Instance.password = passwordField.text.ToString();
            //StartCoroutine(LogInAuthenticate());
 
            Value =  Credentials.Instance.ConvertToJason();
           Debug.Log(Value);
            StartCoroutine(LogInAuthenticate());
        }
 
        loginButton.SetActive(true);
        loadingImg.SetActive(false);
 
    }
    string Value;
    IEnumerator LogInAuthenticate()
    {      
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(Url, Value))
        {          
            www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");          
           
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
           
            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.LogError ("Web Issue : "+ www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("Log Message : " + responseText);
                if (responseText.StartsWith("Authenticate Successfully"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Sucess :" + responseText);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Log Issue : " + responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
}
```

php code is working fine on postman application.
all data is being handled in json, i am using unityweb request, and data directly through string, becuase wwwform was not working out quite like what i expected, maybe i didnt understood it.

i think i am missing some headers or maybe its due to syntex, but there not much help on internet about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the overload [`UnityWebRequest.Post(string url, string data)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) note that

> The data in `postData` **will be escaped**, then interpreted into a byte stream via `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`

In order to avoid this you could rather use

```
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest(Url, "POST"))
{    
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value);
    request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bytes);
    request.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";
    request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    ....
}
```